# Python: More efficient XML lookup with Element Tree

Tags: python, xml

Currently I'm using ElementTree to parse an XML file what contains thousands of objects. The XML looks similar to this (note: there are thousands of objects) :

```
<objects>
    <object> 
         <Name> Name 1 </Name> 
         <attrib1> Attrib1 </attrib1> 
         <attrib2> Attrib2 </attrib2> 
     </object>
 </objects>
```

What I've done is create a function as follows:

```
def objattribs(objname,objects): 
    for o in objects: 
          name = o.find('./Name').text 
          if name = objname: 
                'do something' 
 objname = 'SomeObject' 
 objects =   objects_XML.findall('./object')
 objattribs(objname,objects)
```

The issue I'm having is that this piece is causing my code to run very slow since its finding the name of every object in the XML:

```
 name = o.find('./Name').text
```

Is there a better way to do this and speed up my program ?

Comment: Have you tried just o.find('Name').text, without the dot slash? Find can match a  tag name or path, you're using path where a tag name could be used, which may be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using XPath, as supported by ElementTree:

```
def find_by_name(name, xml):
    return xml.findall("./object[Name='%s']" % name)
```

Where `xml` is an `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` representing `<objects>`. For an XML document of the structure you described above with 10'000 `<object>` child elements I get this result:

```
In [27]: %timeit find_by_name(' Name 8888 ', x)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.73 ms per loop
```

Comment: I was able to reduce run time from 8.7 seconds to 2.4 seconds using this!

Comment: Glad to hear! If I'm after maximum performance, I usually use lxml instead of ElementTree. It's not part of the standard library, though.